# Batch File BigQuery Write to CSV with Pipeline Delimiter

Tags: batch-file, google-bigquery

I'm creating a batch file to run a stored procedure and write my result into CSV from a table in Google BigQuery. My batch file script is like this:

```
set target_dir=C:\Temp\

call bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "call mydataset.sp_test()"

bq query --format=csv --max_rows=3000000 --use_legacy_sql=false ^
"select * from mydataset.test" > %target_dir%TEST_%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%.csv
```

The default delimiter of my .csv file is a comma `,`
how can I change the delimiter to a pipeline `|` or other specified delimiter in my batch file script?

Comment: Would you try it with `--field_delimiter` ?

Comment: I have tried adding --field_delimiter = 'I' but seems like it is not the right syntax..

Comment: Have you tried after removing space between = ?

Comment: Yes, I tried --field_delimiter=| also --field_delimiter='|' both gave me error

Comment: Why are you calling `bq`, it is not a batch file? remove `call`. Also, should it not be `--destination_format=CSV`?

Comment: I thought you'were doing `bq load`.   As I know, `bq query` doesn't support it.

Comment: "bq query" is the syntax to query in Google BigQuery. My batch script I posted above works fine the .csv file is created with that script.. I only need the right syntax to change the delimiter.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference I read here it seems like the syntax `--destination_format=CSV` and `--field_delimiter='|'` works for `bq extract` but not for `bq query` (?)

Comment: `|` is a special character to `cmd`. Usually, you can convert it to an ordinary character by "escaping" it with a caret thus: `^|` Alternatively, try enclosing it in double-quotes `"|"`

Comment: I have tried enclosing it in double quotes but still gave me error. I also tried `--field_delimiter=^|` and `--field_delimiter="^|"` does not work either..

Comment: Yes , `--field_delimiter='|'` works only for `bq extract` but not for `bq query`.As of now there is no way, you can mention any delimiter change in `bq query` command.One workaround is ,replace all the `,` with `|` and then save the output in a `.csv` file(perform this only when you don’t have any commas in your data).